# Packaging Enaml Application with PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyside, pyinstaller, enaml

I have a single window/view enaml application (backend is PySide). I have packaged it to `.exe` using PyInstaller and it finishes successfully but when I run the executable it complains about the module which is in the `.enaml` file (I have already included the file and the parser in the `.spec` file, see below). Any thoughts on what goes wrong?

Here is the error from running the `.exe` file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "colEq.py", line 70, in <module>
    from colEq import CaseView
ImportError: cannot import name CaseView
```

`CaseView` is defined in `colEq.enaml` file and the line referred to is:

```
with enaml.imports():
   from colEq import CaseView`
```

My spec file has the following added beyond the default generated by PyInstaller:

```
a.datas+= [('colEq.enaml', 'colEq.enaml', 'DATA'),
           ('enaml\\core\\parser.py', parser_filepath, 'DATA')]

hiddenimports=[
    "enaml",
    "enaml.core.parse_tab.lextab",
    "enaml.core.compiler_helpers",
    "enaml.core.compiler_nodes",
    "enaml.core.enamldef_meta",
    "enaml.core.template",
    "enaml.widgets.api",
    "enaml.widgets.form",
    "enaml.layout.api",
    "enaml.stdlib.fields"
 ]
```

The platform is Python 2.7, x86, Win 10.

Comment: It looks like you have two modules named the same thing `colEq.py` and `colEq.enaml` try to rename or move one to a separate package.

Comment: @Mahdi have you resolved the issue?

Comment: nope, just moved on.